# Facebook secret key for an already existing page

Tags: facebook

I have a page already registered on facebook pages (but I registered it on my 'normal' facobook and not on developers.facebook.com).
Now I want to know the secret key for my app, but all the answer I found while searching, said that 'just go to the FB developer page, and you will see your app ID/secret key there' (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orx7bhEBUP4 (the admin page also looks different now)). But when I switch to developers.facebook.com (I already registered as developer) I can't find my page in my apps as the typical answers say. I can create a new app, but that will have a new app ID as well, so I assume that it will be a differend app, and I didn't find any option to merge/migrate my developer app with my page registered on FB.

Did somebody faced with similar problems before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An app and a page are two completely different things. There are no app id and secret for pages.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think I mixed up pageID with appID. I'm new in FB development. :)